# How to change the email ID of sender for job locally in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins, the sender email is configured under

```
Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Jenkins Location -> System Admin e-mail address
```

But this is set globally for all jobs in Jenkins. Is there any way this sender email ID can be overridden for a particular jenkins job locally only for that job ?

Kindly suggest.

Comment: What do you want exactly? Are you using the *email-ext-plugin* and do you want to alter this email-address?

Comment: Sender email address is defined in the above mentioned path as part of global setting, that will be used across all jobs.

Retaining the above mail ID, can I use a different email ID as sender address for a particular job ?